# UILabel Text being cut off

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying a to create a Youtube like app. I am not using IB in this project. The issue I am having is the text gets cut off when the sentence is too big to fit in one line. I want to display the first sentence without being cut off just like Original Youtube app. The code for UILabel is given below.

```
let titleLabel:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Linkin Park - Numb"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        return label
    }()
```

//constraints for titlelabel

```
    //top
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Top,       relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))

    //left
  addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: profileImageView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
    //right
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    // height
titleLabelHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0, constant: 44)
        addConstraint(titleLabelHeightConstraint!)
```

The following image can give the idea about what I meant above.
[My App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwzIV.png)

I am also posting the image of original Youtube App. The first sentence never gets cut off in original Youtube app.
[Youtube App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxGnh.png)

Is there any way I can show text just like Youtube in my app?

Comment: try remove the height constraint. it will automatically expand the height.

Comment: Thanks that's worked .

Comment: There is a minor issue. When I delete height constraint the second line does not align properly along with the first line, it moves slightly to the right. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: depends how you add constraint for second label. it should have top margin with the upper label

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:-

```
label.lineBreakMode = .ByCharWrapping
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: I tried yours but it does not display the whole sentence though first line never gets cut off

Answer (score 1):

```
Hi just remove the height constraint 
titleLabelHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0, constant: 44)
        addConstraint(titleLabelHeightConstraint!)

and **add the bottom constraint to the label** as in current scenario the label does't have the bottom constraint so that label does't know how much increase .
```

Comment: I tried yours but  it gets worse if I add bottom constraint since there is another label at the bottom of TitleLabel which has top constraint so I  dont need bottom constraint for TitleLabel.

Answer (score 1):

You did hard fix height constraint of label. Please remove it for dynamic height.

Answer (score -1):

You can manually increase your label width from your main.storyboard if you are using xcode

Comment: The OP stated that IB isn't being used (no storyboards).